# Why onclick() gtag Event does not appear in GA when other events are ok

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

Why this simple event does not fire/appear

```
<a id="menu" href="a.html" onclick="gtag('event', 'navigation', 'menu');">A</a>
```

There is no error in browser js console or *Google tag assistant tool*,  it shows *PageLoads* OK.

The Analytics Events appear OK in Google Analytics for other events, that are executed inside JS React Component like this:

```
  gtag("event", "game", {
    event_category: "Update"
  });
```

Comment: What happens if you click on that link? Are you redirected to another page? a.html in this case.

Comment: yes, link click works,  but bug is that GA does not show event data

Comment: Also a.html appears in GA

Comment: It is possible that the redirect happens before the onclick. Can you tell me which browser are you testing it?

Comment: all browsers, thousands of users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax used is not the same for the two examples:

```
gtag('event', 'navigation', 'menu');
```

should be:

```
gtag('event', 'menu', { event_category: 'navigation' });
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events